# Is there a common name to refer to the groups 13 and 14?

Tags: periodic-table, terminology

The group 15, 16, and 17 are called the pnictogens, chalcogens, and halogens respectively. Is there a name for the groups 13 and 14 as well?

Comment: Heh. It seems that the name for group 13 and 14 elements is... *drums adding the wait for the effect* ...Carbon and Boron groups! [This guy(s)](http://chemteacher.chemeddl.org/services/chemteacher/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=148) seems to use all the other names for the groups, except that they don't use any names for C and B groups. Eh, maybe charcoalgens or something for the Carbon group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the carbon group is known as either the *tetrels* or the *crystallogens*; while the boron group is known as *triels* or *icosagens*. These names are very rarely used.

**Source**: Wikipedia articles on [Carbon family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_group) (also, [crystallogen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crystallogen)) and [Boron family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron_group). Although other (seemingly) respectable sites use them.