# What word is to chalcogen and pnictogen what halide is to halogen?

Tags: nomenclature

Would "chalcide" be understood as a group 16 dianion (and something less electronegative)? Would "pnictide" be understood as a group 15 trianion (and something less electronegative)?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0119186?LI=true 
http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1996/cs/cs9962500199/unauth#!divAbstract
I would've expected chalcide, but that might be overloaded. Looks like the preferred term is "chalcigenide." "Pnictide" seems to be correct.

Comment: Strongly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/is-there-a-common-name-to-refer-to-the-groups-13-and-14

Comment: @Zhe Fairly certain it's because the h is silent in chalcogen (that is, the "ch" in chalcogen makes a /k/ sound, not a /tʃ/ sound), so "chalcide" would sound like "calcide", which would suggest calcium. Pnictide, and halide for that matter, don't have this problem

Answer (score 8):

From what I could find in a brief search, ["pnictide"](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed086p1200)(this link includes some of the origin for the name) is used, but the corresponding term used for group 16 seems to be ["chalcogenide"](https://chalcogenide.net/what-are-chalcogenides/), which, while it can be used to describe all group 16 elements, typically is used in a way that excludes oxides.

Answer (score 7):

Pnictogens and chalcogens are the trivial names for group 15 and 16 elements respectively. [From here:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_sets_of_chemical_elements)

> - Pnictogens – The elements of group 15: N, P, As, Sb, Bi. (Mc had not yet been named when the 2005 IUPAC Red Book was published, and its
>     chemical properties are not yet experimentally known.)
> - Chalcogens – The elements of group 16: O, S, Se, Te, Po. (Lv had not yet been named when the 2005 IUPAC Red Book was published, and its
>     chemical properties are not yet experimentally known.)

So, the corresponding ion names should be pnictide(e.g. nitride, bismuthide) and chalocogenide(e.g. sulfide, selenide, telluride).  Note: salts containing oxygen as anion are called oxide salts but salts containing sulfur, selenium as anion are called chalcogenide salts. Since, salts containing oxygen as anion are **more common** and thus **separately given name** 'oxide salts' and salts containing sulfur, selenium as anion are **less common**, so they are **collectively given name** 'chalcogenide salts'.

Similarly, the trivial name for group 14 elements is **crystallogens** (for its ability to form crystals?) and for group 13 elements is **icosagens** or **triels**. However, these names are very trivial and rarely used.

I have never heard name of group 13 and 14 element ion as crystallogenide or icosagenide. Perhaps, for their inability/difficulty to form corresponding ions(since it is very hard to accept four or five electrons to form ions).