# Is "pentel" a real chemistry term?

Tags: periodic-table, pnictogen

Allegedly "pentel" is a synonym for "pnictogen," that is, an element of group 15, the nitrogen group. However, I have not been able to find any sources to support the existence of this sense of the word except Wikipedia, Wiktionary, Wikidoc, and [these](https://www.thoughtco.com/nitrogen-on-the-period-table-608593) [two](https://www.thoughtco.com/nitrogen-family-of-elements-606642) pages at thoughtco.com by Anne Marie Helmenstine, Ph.D. No other dictionary I've consulted has it, not even the OED. They only mention "pentel" as a certain kind of pen. Helmenstine's article cites

> *Modern Chemistry* (South Carolina). Holt, Rinehart and Winston. Harcourt Education (2009)

but this citation is for the whole article, not specifically for "pentel."

So is this real, or is it a case of [citogensis](https://xkcd.com/978/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Google Scholar (scholar.google.com/) when needed. All I searched was: pentels pnictogen, and the third search result leads to an article in *Angewandte Chemie* which in turn leads to the original source of your requested term. There is a footnote in the Angew. Chem. article "A Deltahedral Zintl Ion Now Made in the Solid-state" by Virginie Queneau and Slavi C. Sevov.

Footnote 1 reads

> The use of triels, tetrels, and pentels or pnictogens has been
> suggested by the Commission of Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry in
> the Inorganic Chemistry Division of IUPAC: B. P. Block, W. H. Powell,
> W. C. Fernelius Inorganic Chemical Nomenclature. Principles and
> Practice, American Chemical Society, Washington, DC, 1990, p. 24.

I respect the Oxford English Dictionary, but sometimes they are very stubborn in not including some chemical terms, such as banana bonds, and anation (reaction). I suggested several times but it fell on deaf ears.

BTW, the 22-volume OED does have Pentel but not in the chemical sense; it is "  A proprietary name for: a type of ballpoint pen typically having a non-metallic tip and a free flow of ink resembling that of a felt-tip pen."

Comment: But they do include [words like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c33AZBnRHks&t=25m57s) *[exptl](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=exptl)* and *muzjik* (?).

Answer (score 7):

Group 13 and group 14 elements are trivially called *triels* and *tetrels* respectively (see previous posts- [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/is-there-a-common-name-to-refer-to-the-groups-13-and-14/27594) and [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86674/what-word-is-to-chalcogen-and-pnictogen-what-halide-is-to-halogen/86677)). By same analogy, group 15 elements are called "pentels".

> **pentel (pnicogen, pnictogen)**
>
> N,P,As,Sb,Bi derived (with contraction) from pent(a)-and element-referring to the fifth main group of the periodic table
>
> <sub>*Elsevier's Dictionary of Chemoetymology: The Whys and Whences of Chemical Nomenclature and Terminology* by Alexander Senning, Elsevier, **2006**</sub>

However, this usage is so rare and uncommon in chemistry that if you search for "pentel" on Google, it will lead to certain ball point pen.

Comment: well... i don't think *any* amount of usage in chemistry would make it competitive in searches with said ballpoint pen company - not least because ballpoint pens are a lot less niche

Comment: @somebody And group 15 probably has a smaller SEO budget than an international stationary manufacturer.